# Materialize carousel keep changing size itself when minimizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I have created materialize full width carousel and height is half. Everything works fine however, my problem is when I tried to minimize the browser and then maximize the browser again the carousel goes into full screen

Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/4"></a>
</div>
```

Here is my JS CODE:

```
$('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
    fullWidth: true
});
```

Comment: is your JS code wrapped in documentReady?

Comment: @PhilippSander yes